# invalid conversion from 'int32_t {aka long int}' to 'const char*'

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino and think this might be easy but can't seem to solve it. I am getting an `invalid conversion from 'int32_t {aka long int}' to 'const char*'`

```
#include <BLEPeripheral.h>
constexpr int32_t file_maximum_byte_count = (50 * 1024);

BLECharacteristic file_maximum_length_characteristic = BLECharacteristic("3002", BLERead, sizeof(uint32_t));
```

In my setup I am doing this:

```
void setup() {
   ...
   blePeripheral.addAttribute(file_maximum_length_characteristic);
   file_maximum_length_characteristic.setValue(file_maximum_byte_count);
   ...
}
```

I guess I need to convert the `file_maximum_length_characteristic` to a `const char*` and on the bluetooth app receives this as an array I believe.

The error is happening on this line:

```
file_maximum_length_characteristic.setValue(file_maximum_byte_count);
```

Here is the library function information:

> instance-method setValue → bool Parameters:
>
> const unsigned char * value unsigned char length // In
> BLECharacteristic public: virtual bool setValue(const unsigned char
> value[], unsigned char length)

Although this doesn't make sense as I can pass in 1 value and have, but it doesn't work when I am receiving the value from the app when I do that.

Here is the [GitHub repo of the library](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-BLEPeripheral).

Comment: Can you tell us which of those lines is associated with the error, and can you provide a link to the documentation for this library?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I added the line.

Comment: I can't be sure because I don't have the documentation for that library, but it looks like `setValue()` needs a `const char *`. Pass it a `const char *` instead of an `int32_t`.

Comment: Added info. It is BLEPeripheral by Sandeep Mistry for the nRF52.

Comment: Can you provide a link? Assume I have limited attention and don't want to do all the work for you.

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't pass in a `const char[]` and a length. Why do you think you can pass an integer to a function that requires not-an-integer?

Comment: I added the link. First this const char + length pops up when I mouse over it, but I have put only `(char) file_maximum_byte_count` and it compiles.

Comment: The API specifies there are two `BELCharacteristic::setValue` methods. One that takes a `char` array and a length, and one that takes a null-terminated string. Pass in either of those. I still don't know why you haven't done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
setValue((uint8_t*)&file_maximum_byte_count, sizeof(file_maximum_byte_count));
```